# RandomAccessFile.close releases file locks for all threads on Linux OpenJDK 8

Tags: java, linux, file-locking

After investigating a bug, I found out that when Thread-B calls `RandomAccessFile.close` on a file (after failing a `RandomAccessFile.getChannel().tryLock()` call), the closing either closes all open streams for the specific file or at least releases the file lock (held by Thread-A for example) for the whole JVM process.

To illustrate, here is some code:

```
public class Locker {
  static FileLock lockFile(String path) {
    try {
      RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(path, "rw");
      try {
        FileLock lock = f.getChannel().tryLock();
        return lock; // Thread-A gets the lock
      }
      catch(OverlappingFileLockException | IOException ex) {
        f.close(); //Thread-B fails and closes, but this also releases the lock of Thread-A
        return null;
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String path = args[0];
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> lockFile(path));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> lockFile(path));
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
  }
}
```

I checked the active locks using the Linux command `lslocks`. The moment `f.close()` is called, `lslocks` reports that there is no lock held by the JVM process anymore.

Is this behavior expected? Does `RandomAccessFile.close` close **all** streams on the specific file opened by the JVM process? This behavior is not reproducible on Windows machines so I'm assuming this is either a Linux JVM bug or some weird Linux filesystem behavior.

EDIT: Using Redhat 4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64 and (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_212-b04)

Comment: it is not clear, are you sharing the instance of `RandomAccessFile` across threads?

Comment: No, it's a new instance. I'll clear up the code.

Comment: I updated the code. Using Redhat 4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64

Comment: Yes, it's my question, I answered with the root cause I found. Now I'm looking to find why it behaves like this.